# Print hadoop properties in CLI

Tags: java, hadoop

Am writing a utility program with Hadoop using java and I need to extract all the hadoop properties in a single command as like `set -v` in `hive` through the Jsch.

I tried this `hadoop org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` but it returns only the core-site properties. Is there any other commands available to print all the properties  like `set -v` in `hive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be:

```
package config;

import java.util.Map.Entry;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;


public class HadoopPropDump extends Configured implements Tool {

  static {

    //Hadoop by default specifies two resources, loaded in-order from the classpath:  
    // 1. core-default.xml
    // 2. core-site.xml

    Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-default.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-site.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-default.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-site.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("yarn-default.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("yarn-site.xml");
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry: conf) {
      System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new HadoopPropDump(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}
```

The static block makes sure that the **`HDFS`**, **`YARN`**, and **`MapReduce`** configurations are picked up, in addition to the core ones (which **`Configuration`** knows about already).”

**Reference:** O'Reilly's "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" by Tom White